# Would this boot select button design work?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, esp32, timing, development

So, I'm back with the need for more advice. This post ties in with my previous post
[here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/705517/click-to-reset-and-hold-to-bootloader-button-design-scheme-for-an-esp32-s3-dev). I recommend you read the previous post because most of the information that I'll be referring to is found there.

I played around with [DELTA12](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/95160/delta12)'s proposed design that was commented in my previous post. In the end, I made a few major changes to fit my needs a lot better, and I believe this will work according to Espressif's timing requirements as stated in the ESP32-S3 datasheet for pin strapping and reset.

Here's the final proposed schematic:
[image]

Assuming C1 = C2 < C3 and IN1- = IN2- > IN3+:

- When power is removed, C1, C2, and C3 all discharge.
- On power-up, R1 charges C1, causing CHIP_PU to flip high from the C1 comparator output after the 50us delay. R1 also charges C2 and C3, C2 flipping GPIO_0 high from the C2 comparator and the C3 comparator should already be outputting high as IN3- has yet to overtake IN3+. This will happen for at least 3 ms so that the MCU can boot normally and not into boot mode. IN3+ is going to be an extremely low voltage compared to IN1- and IN2-, but C3 is going to be a greater value than C1 and C2, to the point where it takes around 2 seconds for C3 to charge via R1.
- On button press, this should put the board into boot mode but not reset. C1 and C2 are completely discharged. CHIP_PU is sent high from the C1 comparator after the delay. C2 comparator is also high, but the C3 comparator is still tying GPIO_0 to ground because C3 didn't completely discharge IN3-, making IN3- still greater than than IN3+ and putting GPIO_0 low for more than 3 ms after CHIP_PU goes high for the strapping pins to be read, successfully putting it into boot mode.
- On button hold, this should reset the board. If the button is held for more than two seconds, all of the capacitors discharge and it imitates it's initial power-up state as previously mentioned.

Would my design work? Is my schematic correct? Will everything do as they are supposed to? I'm a little weary because this is my first complicated schematic like this, but I'm pretty sure everything should do as they are supposed to and wanted to make sure I'm not accidentally causing a short or something like that.

Comment: Welcome to EE stack exchange. Please be aware of the fact that this is not a design check forum. Please ask specific questions.

Comment: @StefanWyss I apologize. I didn't know there were such things as a design check forum. Are you able to link me to a few good ones?

Comment: I don‘t know about design check forums. I just meant that this isn‘t one. Again, if you ask specific questions your chance is high to get good answers 

Comment: If you want to verify the circuit I suggest you to simulate it in LTspice or some similar simulator

Comment: or try this: https://www.falstad.com/circuit/